# The state tax I owe from my return has not been taken - how should I proceed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, new-york

I submitted my New York State resident tax return close to 6 weeks ago. I filled the form (IT-201) on my computer, printed and signed, and then put it in the mail in a random mail box in Manhattan. I didn't have tracking or anything fancy like that: just an old-fashioned handwritten address and stamp.

I owed over $1000 in state tax, and the money has *not* been deducted from my account. Every year I have owed state tax, and in my experience the amount is deducted within a week or two of my return being mailed. So, I'm beginning to worry that the state government has not received my return due to some problem with the mail.

How should I proceed? My main concern is that I've no way to prove that I submitted the return on time, and so I could be hit with late return penalties if I do something naive like just mailing it in again.

Comment: If you can't prove you mailed it, and they didn't get it, you're likely still liable for filing a late return. They have a phone number; call them and ask what to do.

Comment: By coincidence NY State took my tax payment today! Thank you @Todd.

Answer (score 2):

That is typical of how slowly tax authorities move, especially in April.

Next time if it's time sensitive or "cost you money if they don't get it" sensitive, send it certified mail.

You need the little camo-green postcard. The neon green Delivery Confirmation or web site confirmation won't cut it, because USPS doesn't store the data long enough for the glacial speed at which tax authorities move.  8-15 months to get around to flag a return is normal... then they say "you didn't send it timely" and the website says "confirmations only archived for 90 days" and you're outta luck.